# How to calculate my result in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make calculator in React but I'm stuck at this point. I don't know how to set value previous num and next num and operator.

Here is my code for the state

```
this.state={
    value:'0',
    operation:'',        
    previousvalue:'',
    nextvalue:''
}
```

and here is my function code where I'm trying to manage my all calculation:

```
operation(operator) {
    console.log('operator coming',operator);
    // this.setState({ans:this.state.value,operator,this.state.value})
    const previousvalue=this.state.value;
    const nextValue='';
    const result='';
    console.log('this is my previous value',previousvalue);
    if(operator) {
   this.setState({value:'',operation:operator,result:previousvalue+this.state.value})
    console.log('this is my opertor',this.state.operation,result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using "this.state.value" inside setState({}).

Do you mean: `this.setState({ans: this.state.value, operator: this.state.value})`

or do you mean: `this.setState({ans: this.state.value, operator, value})`.

Answer (score 0):

This.setState is asynchronous function try this this.setState({value},()=>{console.log})

SetState accepts callback function in its parameter.

And second thing try to post error also.